# During bulk data operations:: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

Tags: apex, trigger

**Only During bulk data Operations like Dataloader Update or changing Account owner  the following trigger casusing the error.::**
**UpdateRightNowContacts: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries:**
**101**

could you please correct in the code where i was doing mistake.

```
            for(Contact c: a.Contacts)
            {
                c.Return_Campaign__c='Non-processing';
                contacts.add(c);
            } 
        }
    //Update all affected contacts  
    update contacts;
    }
}
```

Comment: To add to Santanu's answer, the effort of correctly indenting is always worth it to avoid getting misled. Its the curly brackets that count not the indenting...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are performing DML inside the `for` loop, thats why the error is. Update contact outside of `for` loop

```
//loop through each account
for(Account a: accounts)
{
    //all your existing logic to prepare contacts list, except DML operation.

}
//Update all affected contacts  
update contacts;
```

Refer [Apex Code Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)

**Update based on this following comments**

> Tried to change One of ACCOUNT OWNER Error:: caused by: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is indexed a filter might still not be selective when: 1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null) 2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs many times): Trigger.UpdateRightNowContacts: line 13, column 1

**Solution**

This is typical design flaws where a single account contains more than 10000 Contacts which is called Account Data Skew.

It is recommended to distribute the Contacts under different accounts so that a single Account should not have 10000 contacts.

Secondly, to perform query optimization, request Salesforce to create Custom Indexes so that not only this query, but also, List Views, Reports performance must be enhanced using those indexes.

Refer [Avoid Account Data Skew for Peak Performance](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/04/avoid-account-data-skew-for-peak-performance.html)

[Improve performance with Custom indexes using Selective SOQL Queries](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006007&type=1)

Thirdly, if there are large volume for records to be updated, consider using batch processes.

Comment: Tried to change One of ACCOUNT OWNER Error:: caused by: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing.
Even if a field is indexed a filter might still not be selective when:
1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null) 2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs many times): Trigger.UpdateRightNowContacts: line 13, column 1

Comment: Welcome to SFSE and thanks for nice question. Please find my updated answer